# Thoughts on foreach with Enumerable.Range vs traditional for loop

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, foreach, c#-3.0

In C# 3.0, I'm liking this style:

```
// Write the numbers 1 thru 7
foreach (int index in Enumerable.Range( 1, 7 ))
{
    Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```

over the traditional `for` loop:

```
// Write the numbers 1 thru 7
for (int index = 1; index <= 7; index++)
{
    Console.WriteLine( index );
}
```

Assuming 'n' is small so performance is not an issue, does anyone object to the new style over the traditional style?

Comment: Now this question, with the SUMMARY FROM MANY ANSWERS included, is REALLY relevant, almost a good-practices model for questions in SO. It should be framed!

Comment: @heltonbiker Wrong---actually including a summary does not fit the SO model. The summary should be removed. SO as a Q&A site separates questions and answers, rather than having a generic idea of a "post".

Comment: The behaviour of both are different depending on what version of .Net you are compiling with. The for loop version may not always keep the execution context especially if you have a yield statement.

Comment: There's another advantage using Range(): you can change the value of index inside the loop, and it won't break your loop.

Comment: This example is misleading, because it's presented as Min-Max, when Enumerable.Range is actually Min+Count.  So Enumerable.Range(3,9) would actually go from 3 to 11.

Comment: Looking forward to the addition of new C# 8.0 features to this thread! 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I find the latter's "minimum-to-maximum" format a lot clearer than `Range`'s "minimum-count" style for this purpose.  Also, I don't think it's really a good practice to make a change like this from the norm that is not faster, not shorter, not more familiar, and not obviously clearer.

That said, I'm not against the idea in general.  If you came up to me with syntax that looked something like `foreach (int x from 1 to 8)` then I'd probably agree that that would be an improvement over a `for` loop.  However, `Enumerable.Range` is pretty clunky.

Comment: With C# 4's named arguments feature, we could add an extension method and call it like this (I don't have a good name for it right now): foreach (int x in Enumerable.Range2(from = 1, to = 8)) {}   Is that better, or worse ;)

Comment: Sorry, that's "(from: 1, to: 8)"

Comment: Personally, that would be too verbose and clunky-looking for me to use (as opposed to a for loop) but I understand that it's to some degree a matter of taste.

Comment: @mquander That looks a lot like the syntax of VB:
`For i = 1 To 8`

Comment: How about stealing `foreach(var x in (1 to 8))` from Scala? It's an Enumerable type.

Comment: Now that C# 9 has `foreach` `GetEnumerator` extension methods and `Range`s, how about `foreach (var x in 1..8)`?

Answer (score 52):

This is just for fun. (I'd just use the standard "`for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)`" loop format myself.)

```
foreach (int i in 1.To(10))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);    // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
}

// ...

public static IEnumerable<int> To(this int from, int to)
{
    if (from < to)
    {
        while (from <= to)
        {
            yield return from++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (from >= to)
        {
            yield return from--;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also add a `Step` extension method too:

```
foreach (int i in 5.To(-9).Step(2))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);    // 5,3,1,-1,-3,-5,-7,-9
}

// ...

public static IEnumerable<T> Step<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int step)
{
    if (step == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("step", "Param cannot be zero.");
    }

    return source.Where((x, i) => (i % step) == 0);
}
```

Comment: public static IEnumerable<int> To(this int from, int to) {
            return Enumerable.Range(from, to);
        }

Comment: @unknown, Enumerable.Range can only count forwards, my version counts backwards too. Your code also produces a different sequence to mine: try "foreach (int i in 5.To(15))".

Comment: Very good, this is the sort of thing I wanted to hear when I posted the question!

Comment: Step() looks wrong. 5.To(10).Step(2) will result in [ 6, 8, 10 ] when [ 5, 7, 9 ] is expected. Plus, Step() is horrible performance wise. What if step is 10?

Comment: @wooohoh: The `Step` method works correctly: `i` is the index, not the value. You're right that the performance isn't great, but this is a proof-of-concept demo, not production code.

Comment: @LukeH That's my fault. I overlooked "(x,i)." Also, I'm sorry I was too negative. I actually liked the idea, implemented(without step), tested its performance, concluded that it needs compiler level support to work reasonably fast in performance sensitive codes. To() was up to ~4x slower than 'for' in the test. However, it's still good for most use cases where performance is not critical.

Comment: @wooohoh: There are some simple optimisations to be made. For example, you could handle the enumerator object directly, maintain your own internal counter and only yield on every nth step. Performance probably still wouldn't be fantastic, but you'd remove the delegate call altogether.

Answer (score 33):

In C# 6.0 with the use of

```
using static System.Linq.Enumerable;
```

you can simplify it to

```
foreach (var index in Range(1, 7))
{
    Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```

Comment: I think that the 7 is the count:public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start,int count)

Comment: at first I didn't understand what is `using static`. It should mention that more readable to write: `Enumerable.Range(1, 7).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

Comment: why the ToList()?

Comment: @Timores, to call ForEach, its a method of the List

Comment: Agreed :-) but both ToList and ForEach work on IEnumerable, so calling ToList should be unnecessarz

Comment: @Timores, I am sorry but IEnumerable doesnt have ForEach

Comment: Oops, you're right, I was sure that ForEach was an extension method of IEnumerable<>. Sorry.

Answer (score 13):

You can actually do this in C# (by providing `To` and `Do` as extension methods on `int` and `IEnumerable<T>` respectively):

```
1.To(7).Do(Console.WriteLine);
```

SmallTalk forever!

Comment: Nice - I assume you'd just create a couple of extension methods for "To" and "Do"?

Comment: I thought that C++ syntax is bad LOL

Comment: Hmmm... To and Do does not work for me? What library is this a part of? I am on .Net 4.0.

Comment: @BlueVoodoo they are extension methods that you need to define.

Comment: I don't like the `Do` extension method. It's clearer if this goes inside a `foreach` loop like others have suggested.

Comment: `Do` would be a `ForEach` extension method in C# that MS decided not to have.

Answer (score 9):

I kind of like the idea. It's very much like Python. Here's my version in a few lines:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> To(this int from, int to, int step = 1) {
        if (step == 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("step", "step cannot be zero");
        // stop if next `step` reaches or oversteps `to`, in either +/- direction
        while (!(step > 0 ^ from < to) && from != to) {
            yield return from;
            from += step;
        }
    }
}
```

It works like Python's:

- `0.To(4)` → `[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]`
- `4.To(0)` → `[ 4, 3, 2, 1 ]`
- `4.To(4)` → `[ ]`
- `7.To(-3, -3)` → `[ 7, 4, 1, -2 ]`

Comment: So a Python range is end-exclusive like C++ STL and D ranges? I like it. As a beginner, I used to favor first..last (end-inclusive) until working with more complex nested loops and images, finally realizing how elegant end-exclusive (begin end) was by eliminating all those +1's and -1's that dirtied the code. In ordinary English though, "to" tends to mean inclusive, so naming your params "start" / "end" may be clearer than "from" / "to".

Comment: `!(step > 0 ^ from < to)` could be rewritten into `step > 0 == from < to`. Or even more terse: use a do-while loop with endcondition `from += step != to`

Answer (score 7):

It seems like quite a long winded approach to a problem that's already solved. There's a whole state machine behind the `Enumerable.Range` that isn't really needed.

The traditional format is fundamental to development and familiar to all. I don't really see any advantage to your new style.

Comment: In some ways. Enumerable.Range becomes just as unreadable when you want to iterate from a min to a max, because the second parameter is a range and needs to be calculated.

Comment: Ah, good point, but that's a different case (that I haven't run into yet). Perhaps an extension method with (start, end) instead of (start, count) would help in that scenario.

Answer (score 7):

I think the foreach + Enumerable.Range is less error prone (you have less control and less ways to do it wrong, like decreasing the index inside the body so the loop would never end, etc.)

The readability problem is about the Range function semantics, that can change from one language to another (e.g if given just one parameter will it begin from 0 or 1, or is the end included or excluded or is the second parameter a count instead a end value).

About the performance, I think the compiler should be smart enough to optimize both loops so they execute at a similar speed, even with large ranges (I suppose that Range does not create a collection, but of course an iterator).

Answer (score 7):

I think Range is useful for working with some range inline:

```
var squares = Enumerable.Range(1, 7).Select(i => i * i);
```

You can each over. Requires converting to list but keeps things compact when that's what you want.

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 7).ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

But other than for something like this, I'd use traditional for loop.

Comment: For example, I just did this in my code to build up a set of dynamic parameters for sql `var paramList = String.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, values.Length).Select(i => "@myparam" + i));`

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(1, 7).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);` **BETTER**

Answer (score 7):

There is no significant performance difference between traditional iteration and range iteration, as Nick Chapsas pointed out in his excellent [YouTube video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jmmz1cInNow) Even the benchmark showed there is some difference in nanoseconds for the small number of iterations. As the loop gets quite big, the difference is almost gone.

Here is an elegant way of iterating in a range loop from his content:

```
private static void Test()
{
    foreach (var i in 1..5)
    {

    }
}
```

Using this extension:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static CustomIntEnumerator GetEnumerator(this Range range)
    {
        return new CustomIntEnumerator(range);
    }
    public static CustomIntEnumerator GetEnumerator(this int number)
    {
        return new CustomIntEnumerator(new Range(0, number));
    }
}

public ref struct CustomIntEnumerator
{
    private int _current;
    private readonly int _end;

    public CustomIntEnumerator(Range range)
    {
        if (range.End.IsFromEnd)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        _current = range.Start.Value - 1;
        _end = range.End.Value;
    }

    public int Current => _current;

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        _current++;
        return _current <= _end;
    }
}
```

**Benchmark result:**
[image: Benchmark result]

I loved this way of implementation. But, the biggest issue with this approach is its inability to use it in the async method.

Comment: Nice! There is also the issue that the [`Range.End`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range.end) has exclusive semantics, so the `foreach (var i in 1..5)` should either enumerate from 1 to 4 or violate the semantics.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. That's a valid point.

Comment: a simpler extension:
        public static IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator(this Range r)
        {
            for (int i = r.Start.Value; i <= r.End.Value; i++) yield return i;
        }

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to have the syntax of some other languages like Python, Haskell, etc.

```
// Write the numbers 1 thru 7
foreach (int index in [1..7])
{
    Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```

Fortunatly, we got F# now :)

As for C#, I'll have to stick with the `Enumerable.Range` method.

Comment: There is a range in C# for a while now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges

Answer (score 6):

## How to use a new syntax today

Because of this question I tried out some things to come up with a nice syntax without waiting for first-class language support. Here's what I have:

```cs
using static Enumerizer;

// prints: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
foreach (int i in 0 <= i < 10)
    Console.Write(i + " ");
```

Not the difference between `<=` and `<`.

I also created a [proof of concept repository on GitHub](https://github.com/BrunoZell/Enumerizer) **with even more functionality** (reversed iteration, custom step size).

A minimal and very limited implementation of the above loop would look something like like this:

```cs
public readonly struct Enumerizer
{
    public static readonly Enumerizer i = default;

    public Enumerizer(int start) =>
        Start = start;

    public readonly int Start;

    public static Enumerizer operator <(int start, Enumerizer _) =>
        new Enumerizer(start);

    public static Enumerizer operator >(int _, Enumerizer __) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    public static IEnumerable<int> operator <=(Enumerizer start, int end)
    {
        for (int i = start.Start; i < end; i++)
            yield return i;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> operator >=(Enumerizer _, int __) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

@Luke:
I reimplemented your `To()` extension method and used the `Enumerable.Range()` method to do it.
This way it comes out a little shorter and uses as much infrastructure given to us by .NET as possible:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> To(this int from, int to)
{ 
    return from < to 
            ? Enumerable.Range(from, to - from + 1) 
            : Enumerable.Range(to, from - to + 1).Reverse();
}
```

Comment: I think .Reverse() will end up loading the entire collection into memory on reading the first item. (Unless Reverse checks the underlying type of iterator and says "Ah, this is an Enumerator.Range object. I'll emit an backward-counting object instead of my normal behavior.")

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure everybody has their personal preferences (many would prefer the later just because it is familiar over almost all programming languages), but I am like you and starting to like the foreach more and more, especially now that you can define a range.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the `Enumerable.Range()` way is more declarative. New and unfamiliar to people? Certainly. But I think this declarative approach yields the same benefits as most other LINQ-related language features.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine there could be scenarios where `Enumerable.Range(index, count)` is clearer when dealing with expressions for the parameters, especially if some of the values in that expression are altered within the loop. In the case of `for` the expression would be evaluated based on the state after the current iteration, whereas `Enumerable.Range()` is evaluated up-front.

Other than that, I'd agree that sticking with `for` would normally be better (more familiar/readable to more people... readable is a very important value in code that needs to be maintained).

Answer (score 2):

I agree that in many (or even most cases) `foreach` is much more readable than a standard `for`-loop when simply iterating over a collection. However, your choice of using `Enumerable.Range(index, count)` isn't a strong example of the value of `foreach` over for.

For a simple range starting from `1, Enumerable.Range(index, count)` looks quite readable. However, if the range starts with a different index, it becomes less readable because you have to properly perform `index + count - 1` to determine what the last element will be. For example…

```
// Write the numbers 2 thru 8
foreach (var index in Enumerable.Range( 2, 7 ))
{
    Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```

In this case, I much prefer the second example.

```
// Write the numbers 2 thru 8
for (int index = 2; index <= 8; index++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```

Comment: I agree - similiar to Spender's comment on iterating from min to max.

Answer (score 1):

I do like the `foreach` + `Enumerable.Range` approach and use it sometimes.

```
// does anyone object to the new style over the traditional style?
foreach (var index in Enumerable.Range(1, 7))
```

I object to the `var` abuse in your proposal. I appreciate `var`, but, damn, just write `int` in this case! ;-)

Comment: Heh, I was wondering when I was going to get dinged for that one :)

Comment: I updated my example so as not to deter from the main question.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you misuse enumeration.

Enumerator provides the means to access all the objects in a container one-by-one, but it does not guarantee the order.

It is OK to use enumeration to find the biggest number in an array. If you are using it to find, say, first non-zero element, you are relying on the implementation detail you should not know about. In your example, the order seems to be important to you.

**Edit**: I am wrong. As Luke pointed out (see comments) it is safe to rely on the order when enumerating an array in C#. This is different from, for example, using "for in" for enumerating an array in Javascript .

Comment: Not sure - I mean, the Range method is built to return an incrementing sequence, so I'm not sure how I'm relying on an implementation detail. Can you (or anyone else) elaborate?

Comment: I do not think it is promised that the sequence returned is incrementing. Of course, it always is in practice. You can enumerate any collection. For many, there are a lot of orders that make sense, and you may get any of them.

Comment: @Marcel, @buti-oxa: The process of enumeration (for example, with foreach) doesn't guarantee any specific ordering in itself, but the ordering *is* determined by the enumerator used: The built-in enumerator for Array, List<> etc will always iterate in element order; for SortedDictionary<>, SortedList<> etc it'll always iterate in key comparison order; and for Dictionary<>, HashSet<> etc there's no guaranteed ordering. I'm pretty confident that you can rely on Enumerable.Range always iterating in ascending order.

Comment: Sure, the enumerator knows the order it provides, so if I write the enumerator, I can rely on order. If compiler/library does is for me, how do I know. Does it say somewhere in spec/documentation that built-in enumerator for array always iterate from 1 to N? I could not find this promise.

Comment: @buti-oxa, Take a look at section 8.8.4 (page 240) of the C#3 spec: "For single-dimensional arrays elements are traversed in increasing index order, starting with index 0 and ending with index Length – 1." (http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc)

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing my hat into the ring.

I define this...

```
namespace CustomRanges {

    public record IntRange(int From, int Thru, int step = 1) : IEnumerable<int> {

        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() {
            for (var i = From; i <= Thru; i += step)
                yield return i;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            => GetEnumerator();
    };

    public static class Definitions {

        public static IntRange FromTo(int from, int to, int step = 1)
            => new IntRange(from, to - 1, step);

        public static IntRange FromThru(int from, int thru, int step = 1)
            => new IntRange(from, thru, step);

        public static IntRange CountFrom(int from, int count)
            => new IntRange(from, from + count - 1);

        public static IntRange Count(int count)
            => new IntRange(0, count);

        // Add more to suit your needs. For instance, you could add in reversing ranges, etc.
    }
}
```

Then anywhere I want to use it, I add this at the top of the file...

```
using static CustomRanges.Definitions;
```

And use it like this...

```
foreach(var index in FromTo(1, 4))
    Debug.WriteLine(index);
// Prints 1, 2, 3

foreach(var index in FromThru(1, 4))
    Debug.WriteLine(index);
// Prints 1, 2, 3, 4

foreach(var index in FromThru(2, 10, 2))
    Debug.WriteLine(index);
// Prints 2, 4, 6, 8, 10

foreach(var index in CountFrom(7, 4))
    Debug.WriteLine(index);
// Prints 7, 8, 9, 10

foreach(var index in Count(5))
    Debug.WriteLine(index);
// Prints 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

foreach(var _ in Count(4))
    Debug.WriteLine("A");
// Prints A, A, A, A
```

The nice thing about this approach is by the names, you know exactly if the end is included or not.