# Performance of Enumerable.Range vs for loop

Tags: c#, .net, performance, for-loop, enumerable

I wondered what the performance overhead is of using `Enumerable.Range` was against using a `foreach` loop.  For example:

```
var stringArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(i => string.Empty).ToArray();
```

VS.

```
var stringArray = new string[4];
for (int i = 0; i < formatted.Length; i++)
{
    stringArray[i] = string.Empty;
}
```

I spotted these question:

1. [Why is Enumerable.Range faster than a direct yield loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408452/why-is-enumerable-range-faster-than-a-direct-yield-loop)
2. [Enumerable.Range implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520136/enumerable-range-implementation)
3. [Thoughts on foreach with Enumerable.Range vs traditional for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915745/thoughts-on-foreach-with-enumerable-range-vs-traditional-for-loop)

But I fear with the `Select` at the end then I might be, in effect, loop twice.  However I like the elegance of using the `Range` option.

Comment: When you want to know [which is faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) just test it yourself.

Comment: The only overhead the 1st method has is the instantiation of a few objects. `ToArray` will be the biggest culprit. But this is not a performance issue you need to be concerned about (usually). This is micro-optimization.

Comment: @Dennis_E it was more curiosity than anything else. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the following test the `for` is more efficient: (in milliseconds it is +-3 ms difference - which is insignificant..)

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
var stringArra1y = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(i => string.Empty).ToArray();
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks); //3305

watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
var stringArray2 = new string[4];
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray2.Length; i++)
{
    stringArray2[i] = string.Empty;
}
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks); //1
```

But you can instead of using `Enumerable.Range().Select` use `.Repeat`:

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
var stringArra1y = Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, 4).ToArray();
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks); //391
```

After saying the above notice that you are talking here about very small collections (4 items). In larger collections, and especially if you remove the `.ToArray()` it doesn't behave the same:

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
var stringArra1y = Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, 100000);
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks); //360


watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
var stringArray2 = new string[100000];
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray2.Length; i++)
{
    stringArray2[i] = string.Empty;
}
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks); //1335
```

---

> But I fear with the Select at the end then I might be, in effect, loop twice

Looking though the [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,7865685802e14913) both the `.Range` and `Repeat` are implemented with a `yield return`:

```
static IEnumerable<int> RangeIterator(int start, int count) {
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) yield return start + i;
}
```

So it too id deffered executed, just like the `.Select` meaning it does not loop twice.

*Not that the use of the `Stopwatch` returns different results each run but the overall idea is as presented above*

**IMO**, especially in the case of small collections go for readability over hese minor performance improvements. When you already hit performance issues, only after getting the bigger fish (for instance nested `for` loops on `List<>` instead of using a `HashSet<>`), deal with stuff like this.

Comment: A loop is by far the fastest but very ugly (IMHO) but repeat isn't too bad on performance and is still elegant (IMHO).  Many thank

Comment: Outstanding, it was the deferred execution of the loop I couldn't see

Comment: "go for readability over hese minor performance improvements" - is the "Enumerable.Range" even more readable? looks like the [community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915745/thoughts-on-foreach-with-enumerable-range-vs-traditional-for-loop/36591435) prefers the traditional for loop?

Answer (score 1):

In my very simple test it looks like for loop is faster by 38ms for 1 000 000 strings.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var start = DateTime.Now;
            EnTest();
            var end = DateTime.Now;

            var firstResult = end - start;
            Console.WriteLine("Difference for Enumerable: {0}ms", firstResult.Milliseconds);

            GC.Collect();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            var secondStart = DateTime.Now;
            ArTest();
            var secondEnd = DateTime.Now;

            var secondResult = secondEnd - secondStart;
            Console.WriteLine("Difference for loop: {0}ms", secondResult.Milliseconds);

            var globalResult = firstResult - secondResult;
            Console.WriteLine("Difference between tests: {0}ms", globalResult.Milliseconds);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void EnTest()
        {
            var stringArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(i => string.Empty).ToArray();
        }

        public static void ArTest()
        {
            var stringArray = new string[1000000];
            for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
            {
                stringArray[i] = string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Lopp are fast but ugly, `Repeat` was what I was looking for, thanks