# Quicker way to add items to an array with a formula

Tags: c#

I have this code block

```
double[] tabHeight = { 16, 10, 15, 20 };
double[] tabMidSectionWA = { 6, 2, 5, 6 };

double[] tabCurveWA = {
           (tabHeight[0] - tabMidSectionWA[0]) / 2 ,
           (tabHeight[1] - tabMidSectionWA[1]) / 2,
           (tabHeight[2] - tabMidSectionWA[2]) / 2 ,
           (tabHeight[3] - tabMidSectionWA[3]) / 2 
};
```

Is there an easier way to add these values using the formula of `(tabheight - tabMid) / 2` using a for loop or foreach?

Comment: `using a for loop or foreach` you pretty much answered your own question?

Comment: Are you looking for a Linq expression?

Comment: @Longoon12000 im looking a code example...

Comment: Are `tabHeight` and `tabMidSectionWA` guaranteed to have the same length?

Comment: @ZoharPeled what do you mean?

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-for-loop

Comment: Do they both always have the same number of elements, or can one have more elements than the other?

Comment: I'd actually make that a class with `Height` and `MidSection` Properties and a readonly Property `Curve` that applies the formula ( maybe even in the contructor and the class being immutable). Then you could have a list of that class instead of two arrays.

Comment: Do you want something like`double[] tabCurveWA = tabHeight.Select((e, i) => (e - tabMidSectionWA[i]) / 2).ToArray();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Linq :

```
double[] tabHeight = { 16, 10, 15, 20 };
double[] tabMidSectionWA = { 6, 2, 5, 6 };

double[] tabCurveWA = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(tabHeight.Length, tabMidSectionWA.Length))
                                .Select(i => (tabHeight[i] - tabMidSectionWA[i]) / 2)
                                .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", tabCurveWA)); // outputs 5, 4, 5, 7
```

`Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(tabHeight.Length, tabMidSectionWA.Length))` will create a sequence from 0 and of a size of the lowest value between `tabHeight.Length` and `tabMidSectionWA.Length` (to avoid an `IndexOutOfRangeException`)

Then, `Select(i => (tabHeight[i] - tabMidSectionWA[i]) / 2)` sets every number of this sequence (`0` to `3` in this example) in `i` and apply `(tabHeight[i] - tabMidSectionWA[i]) / 2`, creating another sequence.

Finally, `ToArray()` transforms the sequence in an array

Comment: Thank you! I think I'll go with this answer!

Comment: I've just read through the xmldoc given for the methods in visual studio. A few of them I've come across already

Answer (score 6):

You could use Linq with [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netcore-2.0)

```
var result = tabHeight.Zip(tabMidSectionWA,(x,y)=>(x-y)/2).ToArray();
```

`Enumerable.Zip` applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two sequences, producing a sequence of the results.

Output

[image]

Comment: This is a good alternative. Definitely something I'll look into as I've never come across this

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
double[] tabHeight = { 16, 10, 15, 20 };
double[] tabMidSectionWA = { 6, 2, 5, 6 };
var minLength = Math.Min(tabHeight.Length, tabMidSectionWA.Length);
double[] tabCurveWA = new double[minLength];

for (var i = 0; i < minLength; i++)
{
    tabCurveWA[i] = (tabHeight[i] - tabMidSectionWA[i]) / 2;
}
```

Comment: This is a nice simple alternative to be honest

Comment: It's fastest way too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129813/performance-of-enumerable-range-vs-for-loop However, with such a small collection, performance should not be an issue for you.

Answer (score 2):

one of linq way :

```
double[] tabHeight = { 16, 10, 15, 20 };
double[] tabMidSectionWA = { 6, 2, 5, 6 };

double[] tabCurveWA = tabHeight.Select ((x, index) => (x - tabMidSectionWA[index])/2).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a class like this:

```
class Item // please find a better name
{
   public double Height {get;}
   public double MidSection {get;}
   public double Curve {get;}

   public Item( double height, double mid )
   {
       // TODO add Sanity Checks
       Height = height;
       MidSection = mid;
       Curve = height - mid / 2;
   }
}
```

And instead of two arrays have an array or list of that class.

As @Longoon states in comment, this could also be done with a struct.
The idea, however, I wanted to produce is introducing a layer of abstraction. And there are other benefits coming along with this:

- for example, this inherently enforces the same number of `height` and 
  `midSection` Elements.
- it's *readable*
- it's easy to understand
- if you fix naming, it shouldn't surprise clients

TL;DR: I think this is more "clean code" than the (very good) Linq-Answers.

Comment: Could also be a struct

Comment: @Longoon12000 while that's true, there are some perks with structs. I'd try with a class first and then see if making it a struct holds enough benefits. But it's definitely something to think about, yes. This answer is also more about the idea to create a layer of abstraction more than the exact details of implementation.